# Delphi 11 and Indy HTTPS : Error Could not load SSL Library

Tags: ssl, https, indy, get-request, delphi-11-alexandria

I worked with RAD Studio Delphi Enterprise 10.2 (Tokyo) and its preinstalled Indy implementation. To connect to an HTTPS server using `TIdHTTP.Get()`, I created my own class derived from `TIdHTTP`, as follows:

```pascal
type
  TCustomIdHTTP = class(TIdHTTP)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  private
    procedure OnStatusInfoEx(ASender: TObject; const AsslSocket: PSSL; const AWhere, Aret: TIdC_INT; const AType, AMsg: String);
  end;

{ TCustomIdHTTP }

constructor TCustomIdHTTP.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  with IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL do begin    
    OnStatusInfoEx := Self.OnStatusInfoEx;
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1];
  end;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

procedure TCustomIdHTTP.OnStatusInfoEx(ASender: TObject; const AsslSocket: PSSL; const AWhere, Aret: TIdC_INT;
  const AType, AMsg: String);
begin
  SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, Request.Host);
end;

var IdHTTP1: TCustomIdHTTP;
```

This worked perfectly.

Now, I bought a new laptop with Windows 11 and installed Delphi Enterprise 11 (Alexandria), and I get an exception when calling `TIdHTTP.Get()`:

> EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary (Could not load SSL Library)

I really searched the Internet and read many pages, but I could not find a solution.

I tried to copy the last version of the SSL DLLs `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`, but I didn't succeed.

Is there something different now in Delphi 11?

Answer (score 2):

> I really searched the Internet and read many pages, but I could not find a solution.

Just about any website that talks about this error would have explained to you how to fix it. Including *numerous* questions here on StackOverflow.

> I tried to copy the last version of the SSL DLLs `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`, but I didn't succeed.

After the error occurs, you can call Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out WHY Indy wasn't able to load the SSL library. But most likely, you are simply using the wrong version of the DLLs. `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` supports only up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u, which you can get from Indy's [OpenSSL Binaries](https://github.com/indySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries) repo on GitHub. If you want to use OpenSSL 1.1.x+ with Indy, you will have to use [this SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/indySockets/indy/pull/299) instead (note: work-in-progress), or alternatively you can use [sgcIndy](https://www.esegece.com/products/sgcindy).

Also, make sure the DLLs are put somewhere that Indy can find them. Preferably in your application's installation folder.  But, if you need to store them somewhere else, you can call Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit at program startup.

> Is there something different now in Delphi 11?

No, nothing has changed in Delphi 11 in this regard.

---

Also, just FYI, you *do not* need to call `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name()` manually, as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` handles that internally for you, and has done so since 2016 (Delphi 10.2 Tokyo was released in 2017).

Answer (score 0):

Didnt work for me either. I tried OpenSSL 1.0.2u dll and got this response from WhichFailedToLoad()

OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms (error #0)

Also using libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll both version 1.1.1m. Also tried 1.1.1t

Comment: OK found the issue,  for me it was tbbmalloc64.dll from intel memory management.